# CS50 - PSET 3 - Tideman - lock_pairs() works when I test it, but fails unit testing

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

I am at my wits end. I have done my own unit testng and I am getting good results. So, I don't know why check50 is returning errors.

Tideman problem description:
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/3/tideman/

CS50 IDE:
https://ide.cs50.io

The lock_pairs method:
`The function should create the locked graph, adding all edges in decreasing order of victory strength so long as the edge would not create a cycle.`

Here is the error

```
:( lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
    lock_pairs did not lock all pairs
:) lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
:( lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
```

I am hesitant to look up other similar questions because of the CS50 'honor code' on plagiarism. So, please indulge me this oft-repeated question.

Here is the method:

```
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // count forward
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        int winner = pairs[i].winner;
        int loser = pairs[i].loser;

        if (check_cycle_winner(winner, loser, i) && check_cycle_loser(loser, winner, i))
        {
            locked[winner][loser] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            locked[winner][loser] = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Here are the 'helper' functions:

```
bool check_cycle_winner(int winner, int loser, int index)
{
    if (winner == loser) return true;

    if (index == 0) return false;

    return check_cycle_winner(winner, pairs[index - 1].loser, index -1);
}

bool check_cycle_loser(int loser, int winner, int index)
{
    if (loser == winner) return true;

    if (index == 0) return false;

    return check_cycle_loser(loser, pairs[index - 1].winner, index -1);
}
```

Full program (to test in CS50 IDE):
https://replit.com/@A1cmae0n/PSET3-Tideman#main.c

Testing lock_pairs in replit:
https://replit.com/@A1cmae0n/CS50-PSET3-Tideman-lockpairs#main.c

Any input would be appreciated. Please indulge me the request to respond Socratically to my question rather than spoil the answer :)

Comment: Please post your code here, not at a remote site. And you need to explain what it's supposed to do, we don't have the CS50 problem sets memorized.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mistaken because you are looking for full cycles, not for chains, and you should be looking for the latter.

[If it helps here I explain the logic of lock pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74868084/14714821)

> a) You want to lock pair 4 but...
>
> b) pairs[4].loser returns 0, meaning the loser is id 0
>
> c) id 0 won at locked[0][2]
>
> d) id 2 won at locked[2][4]
>
> e) Thus if you lock locked[5][0] as true you create a chain, so you
> shouldn't